# How do CPUShares work across parent and children cgroups?

Tags: linux, docker, cgroup, resource-management, namespaces

Redhat has a [great blog post](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/cgroups-part-two) describing CPUShares, but it assumes processes reside in **leaf** CGroups, and doesn't discuss how CPU time is calculated for processes that reside in **branch** CGroups.

**For example: what is the CPU usage for each of these processes?**

- CGroup A (CPU Shares: 1024)

  - Process 1 (spinning at max CPU)
- CGroup B (CPU Shares: 512)

  - Process 2 (spinning at max CPU)
  - CGroup C (CPU Shares: 256)

    - Process 3 (spinning at max CPU)
  - CGroup D (CPU Shares: 128)

    - Process 4 (spinning at max CPU)

| Process | CPU Usage (%) |
| --- | --- |
| Process 1 | ??? |
| Process 2 | ??? |
| Process 3 | ??? |
| Process 4 | ??? |

I'd love it if someone could help clarify this for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the hierarchy you laid out above appears valid https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html rules out this kind of hierarchy. The documents use the phrase "No Internal Process Constraint". According to these:
"...Non-root cgroups can distribute domain resources to their children only when they don't have any processes of their own. In other words, only domain cgroups which don't contain any processes can have domain controllers enabled in their "cgroup.subtree_control" files."

Since your hierarchy would need CGroupB to have +pids and +cpu enabled in cgroup.subtree_control AND Process2 runs in CGroupB it contravenes this rule.

Running tests on Debian 11 to confirm this.
If I put +pids and +cpu in CGroupB and launch a process2 in CGroupB I can't launch processes 3 & 4 in CGroupC and CGroupD.

However without a process in CGroupB I can launch processes 3 & 4 in CGroupC and CGroupD.
The simple (top) results for CPU Share were:
CGroupA : 66.3%
CGroupC : 22.1%
CGroupD : 10.9%

This close enough to the maths that should apply i.e.
CGroupA Process 1 = 1024/(1024+512) i.e. 2/3rds
CGroupC Process 3 = 512/(1024+512) * 256/(128+256) i.e. 2/9ths
CGroupC Process 4 = 512/(1024+512) * 128/(128+256) i.e. 1/9th

PS. Enough for now ... I have more results, send an email/DM if you're interested..

Cheers

Vernon

the slight discrepancies are because there remain other processes in the rest of the cgroupv2 hierarchy (e.g. in system.slice) that continue to run.